# Migrating python with selenium from mac to pc

Tags: python, macos, selenium, xpath, cross-platform

For me this should be quite straight forward but I am having some issues.

I have some python code that runs perfectly on my mac (up to date OS py27), but now that I am trying to bring the code to my pc to schedule and fully automate (win8 py27) I am getting errors on code that otherwise works fine.

The code is like this:

```
def getElementsByxPath(mydriver,xPath,argKeys):

   try:

       a = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath);
       a.send_keys(argKeys) 
       #error caused here. mac handles error on sending keys while it seems windows does not.
       return a;
   except:
       print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0];
       return 0;


elem = olrHelper.getElementsByxPath(mydriver, ".//tr[@class='list-item']");

for e2 in elem:
    time.sleep(2)

    tryClick(e2)

    try:
        listingID = e2.get_attribute("data-id") #listingID is populated when I debug
        #additionally e2.is_displayed()==True



        field1 = extractAddress(protectedExtractText(olrHelper.getElementByxPath(mydriver, ".//h1", "")))
        #field1 is not populated and returns my default exception value. very odd.
    except:
        print 'error'
```

On my mac this code works (selenium). On my pc this does not work (selenium).

On the PC the xpath element cannot be found.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I assumed I would have cross OS functionality quite easily.

Thank you

Comment: This is marked with [tag:selenium] and [tag:python] but `getElementsByxPath` is not a call available in the Python bindings of Selenium (I grepped through the whole source). There's also a bunch of calls to code that seems to be yours (e.g. `extraAddress(...)`). Your `try` statement is also not terminated. You should update your question so that it shows how the problem happens when you only use actual Selenium calls and make sure that the code is in executable shape.

Comment: Remove all `try/except` blocks and post the full error traceback. Thanks.

Comment: (@Louis line 5 is where he uses the selenium python bindings to find the element.)

Comment: You **really** should show the traceback.

Comment: what was `argKeys` when it broke?

Answer (score -1):

My first guess is that the problem is not with your Python code at all, but with a discrepancy in the HTML as it is "fixed up" by the browsers on the different OS's. In other words, I suspect that one of the browsers is slightly modifying the received HTML to make rendering easier. I'd "View Source" on both files and WinDiff them.

Comment: Hey unfortunately I see the element with the exact same definition on PC as I do on MAC

Comment: Taking Louis' approach further, I would create a local HTML doc that is the simplest possible version of the full-blown doc that still creates the error. In doing this you can isolate the very core of the error.

Comment: Also I would suggest renaming your function to something more accurate like SendKeysToNodeAtPath

Comment: Is this really an answer, or just a comment?

Comment: It's an approach, and hopefully a helpful one. This site is supposed to be about helping, not nitpicking about definitions.